# Como selecionar um elemento baseado no conteúdo

Tags: html, css

Eu tenho uma tabela

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Link</th>
    <th>Descrição</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Fonts para web</td>
    <td><a href="https://fonts.google.com/">Google Fonts</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Caracteres especias</td>
    <td><a href="https://unicode-table.com/en/">Unicode Table</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Eu gostaria de mudar a cor de fundo de todo `<td>` que te possui um `<a>` dentro dele.

```
td => a{
background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem um hake que pode te ajudar, vc coloca `position: relative` na `td` e se tiver um `<a>` filho direto da `td`, vai ter um *pseudo-elemento* que vai cobrir a célula inteira da `td` e colocar a cor de fundo.

Veja o exemplo, repare que independente da posição do `<a>` no conteúdo da `td` a cor vai sempre cobrir a célula inteira.

```css
td {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
td > a:first-of-type::before {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Link</th>
    <th>Descrição</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Fonts para web</td>
    <td>
      <a href="https://fonts.google.com/">link</a>
      <a href="https://fonts.google.com/">link1</a>
      <a href="https://fonts.google.com/">link2</a>
      <a href="https://fonts.google.com/">link3</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Caracteres especias</td>
    <td>texto qualquer</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Caracteres especias</td>
    <td>
      <span>texto + link</span>
      <br>
      <a href="https://fonts.google.com/">link3</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```